# What manuscript is this illustration from?

Tags: identification-request, manuscripts

What manuscript is this illustration from?

[image]

Comment: Where did you get this image? A simple copy paste without any context will not help in identifying easily. Please understand that we are not google image search to identify every Hindu image. Add context and info where you found this photograph and further details if you have. Read the tag wiki of [tag:identification-request] and [ask] page.